QMYSQL Plugin Available But Still Get "Driver not loaded"
I'm writing a C++ app with Qt that needs to connect to a MySQL database.  I can't seem to get QSqlDatabase to actually load the actually available QMYSQL plugin.
Qt 6.7.2. on Mac (macOS 12.7.6, x86_64, yes, I'm on old hardware).
MySQL 8.0.34 installed.
I built the libqsqlmysql.dylib file (and others) using cmake and installed them into the correct ~/Qt/6.7.2/macos/plugins/sqldrivers/ folder.  Some test code using QPluginLoader can load it just fine but QSqlDatabase still can't use it.
The project's .pro file contains (SOURCES, HEADERS & FORMS, which I'm not listing to keep this more brief):
QT +- core gui sql
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): Qt += widgets
TARGET = AppName
TEMPLATE += app
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNING QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x60000
...

The MainWindow.cpp file includes:
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

#include <QSettings>
#include <QCloseEvent>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QLibraryInfo>
#include <QPluginLoader>

// ... and #include statements for app specific code, dialogs, etc.

The MainWindow class' constructor contains:
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    _db = new QSqlDatabase;
    _db->addDatabase ("QMYSQL", "only");

    qDebug () << "Available SQL Drivers :: " << _db->drivers ();
    qDebug () << "_db->driverName () == " << _db->driverName ();
    qDebug () << "_db->isValid () == " << _db->isValid ();
    qDebug () << "_db->lastError () == " << _db->lastError ();
    qDebug () << "_db->isDriverAvailable (\"QMYSQL\") == " << _db->isDriverAvailable ("QMYSQL");

    qDebug () << "QLibraryInfo::isDebugBuild () == " << QLibraryInfo::isDebugBuild ();
    qDebug () << "QLibraryInfo::isSharedBuild () == " << QLibraryInfo::isSharedBuild ();
    qDebug () << "QLibraryInfo::path (QLibraryInfo::PluginsPath" << QLibraryInfo::path (QLibraryInfo::PluginsPath);
    QPluginLoader mysqlPlugin = QPluginLoader ("/Users/lamontp/Qt/6.7.2/macos/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.dylib", this);
    mysqlPlugin.load ();
    qDebug () << "mysqlPlugin.isLoaded () == " << mysqlPlugin.isLoaded ();
    qDebug () << "mysqlPlugin.errorString () == " << mysqlPlugin.errorString ();

    ReadSettings();
    setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac (true);
}

"Application Output" shows:
Available SQL Drivers ::  QList("QSQLITE", "QMARIADB", "QMYSQL", "QODBC", "QPSQL", "QMIMER")
_db->driverName () ==  ""
_db->isValid () ==  false
_db->lastError () ==  QSqlError("", "Driver not loaded", "Driver not loaded")
_db->isDriverAvailable ("QMYSQL") ==  true
QLibraryInfo::isDebugBuild () ==  false
QLibraryInfo::isSharedBuild () ==  true
QLibraryInfo::path (QLibraryInfo::PluginsPath "/Users/lamontp/Qt/6.7.2/macos/plugins"
mysqlPlugin.isLoaded () ==  true
mysqlPlugin.errorString () ==  "Unknown error"

The QMYSQL driver is available (if I remove the libqsqlmysql.dylib file from the plugins/sqldrivers/ directory and run the code again, it disappears from that list).
I ran my code from the command line using the QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS environment variable (trimmed output to just the relevant bits:
qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: looking at "/Users/lamontp/Qt/6.7.2/macos/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.dylib"
qt.core.plugin.loader: Found metadata in lib /Users/lamontp/Qt/6.7.2/macos/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QSqlDriverFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "QMYSQL",
            "QMARIADB"
        ]
    },
    "archlevel": 2,
    "className": "QMYSQLDriverPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 395008
}


qt.core.plugin.factoryloader: Got keys from plugin meta data QList("QMYSQL", "QMARIADB")

Seems to say that this is a release only build, so I switched to building Release and it still doesn't work.  Indeed, I don't have a libqsqlmysql_debug.dylib file, either (I later built it).
I followed every bit of documentation I could find, which are all geared to the problem being that people haven't built the QMYSQL driver, but I have built it.  There's nothing I've been able to find about the driver not actually working in QSqlDatabae even though it is available.
I read through everything I could find on this site and none of them have made any difference.
I have spent evenings and weekends for about a week now searching high and low through here, Qt's documentation and the Internet at large.  The driver is built and in the right location.  I've tested loading it with QPluginLoader, probed it with all the QLibrary, QLibraryInfo, etc. classes and those show it's good), I've manually put the plugins/ directory with the sqldrivers/ directory into the Debug and Release build folders and tried various permutations of directory structures; it still doesn't work.  I think I've done all the due diligence that can be done here.  Obviously, I'm missing something but I certainly am not seeing any useful information on what that might be.  The debugger hasn't helped me see a reason why it doesn't actually load.
Please:
GRANT INSIGHT TO 'thisuser' ON my_weird_question;


During some testing, I deleted all of the sqldrivers and rebuilt and installed just the Debug ones and saw the available drivers list was empty when running the debug build of the app.  When I built and installed Release sqldrivers, they showed up again running debug build of my app.

Probably should ignore this; it only worked for one run of the binary.  I relaunched, without recompiling the program or the plugins, no changes to the running MySQL DB and it no longer worked.  Still not working today; trying more debugger.
I built the libqsqlmysql_debug.dylib by telling qt-cmake to specifically run a debug build by setting -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug (I also switched to using the libmysql.21.dylib file from the server install (MySQL's installer) instead of the libmysqlclient.24.dylib file from the client install (brew).  This let me spend some quality time with the debugger and I found that the _db->addDatabase ("QMYSQL", "only"); call I was making was actually returning the correct object, so I decided to refactor how I was doing this and got it working.  Mainly, the QSqlDatabase *_db private member is now QSqlDatabase _db (no longer a pointer, but the object itself).
Here's the working code in the top of my QMainWindow constructor:
QSqlDatabase::addDatabase ("QMYSQL", "only");
_db = QSqlDatabase::database ("only");

I changed all of the _db-> to _db., of course and got rid of delete _db; from the destructor.  The resulting output from the qDebug () lines shows that it is loaded and the object isValid () call returns true.
